# Problema con aggregate en mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, agregación

buenas tardes, tengo este problema que espero me puedan ayudar a resolver.
Tengo un modelo llamado calificaciones que tiene un código de tipo number y que tiene los datos: 3,2,1. Quiero agrupar solo los valores que tengan 3 en el código y que me diga la cantidad de veces que esta en 3.

Este proceso lo llevo desde el controlador de calificacionParqueadero el cual llama a calificaciones: { type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'calificaciones' } en el modelo.

El código llega hasta la linea 6 y no entra al aggregate, lo que hace es salir al catch.

[[image: ejemplo del código[1]]

Comment: Pon el código como tal y no en imagen, ya que es más fácil visualizarlo, y de ser necesario copiarlo o editar para mostrar el error, también deberías poner una marca donde dices que llega

Comment: Si agrego el código, me genera un error y no me deja publicar la pregunta,

Comment: Hola, es muy extraño eso que dices de que te genera error. Puedes copiar y pegar el código, luego lo seleccionas y presionas `CTRL + K` para indicar que es código y se le asigne el formato adecuado. Saludos

Comment: Una cosa que veo es que estás usando un bloque `try catch` pero no capturas el error, para poder depurar lo que te bota Mongoose. Deberías tener: `catch(error) { console.log(error.message); ...}`, así sabrás al menos cuál es el error que te arroja. Saludos

Comment: Saludos Mauricio, me funcionó, muchas gracias!!